# Call GetClientRect winAPI

Tags: c#, winapi, getclientrect

I am having an issues trying to call the GetClientRect and passing in a Stuct to get populated with the values that are returned.  Here is the code I have.

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref RECT lpRect);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct RECT
        {
            internal int left;
            internal int top;
            internal int right;
            internal int bottom;
        }
     RECT rect = new RECT();

     GetClientRect(PApplication.Instance.MdiMain.Handle, ref rect);
```

I keep getting the error on the RECT saysing Error  1   Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement.

I just need help getting back the left top right bottome values from the GetClientRect

Comment: Where did you put those lines?

Comment: when you said that I looked again I forgot to wrap my code {} after the if. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found it I put the code after an if and forgot to add { } so I am good now.