# Paramaters of Functions Imported Using the DllImport Attribute

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

I am trying to import some winapi functions into my wpf project(written in c#) but I do not know how to "convert" some of their paramaters, for example the function

```
BOOL WINAPI GetClientRect(
  _In_  HWND   hWnd,
  _Out_ LPRECT lpRect
);
```

takes a pointer to a RECT struct and modifies its contents. If I were to import this function using the DllImport attribute it would look like:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll"]
public static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hwnd, ???);
```

How do I handle the pointer to RECT object?

Comment: There is a site full of pinvoke: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getclientrect . Have you tried them? There is a definition for a RECT.

Comment: (note that sometimes that site is wrong :-) They have some problems with 32-to-64 bits)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086927/call-getclientrect-winapi

Comment: well looks like pinvoke.net should do it.. i should have asked here first before searching myself for hours lol ...

Comment: Then you should better your google-fu... If you search for *GetClientRect pinvoke* then the first link is for pinvoke.net, the third is for the stackoverflow answer linked by mpiatek

Comment: There is a Pinvoke.Net plugiun for Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
```